# using $timeout to wait before trying a DB hit again

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I'm making an add to my database, but the db may be waiting for a file to finish uploading.  So, my solution is to try the add, and if the file isn't there, my server returns 404.  If I get a 404 error, I wait 1 second and try again.

This is my thinking:

```
$scope.add() = function() {
    db.add(uuid).then(
        function(response) {
            // Add success!
        },
        function(error) {
            if (error.status === 404) {
                $timeout($scope.add, 1000);
            }
        }
};
```

Is this the right way to be doing this?  Doesn't feel right, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually a legitimate way to do this, except you don't need the parentheses in the timeout's callback. use: `$timeout($scope.add, 1000);`
I would also add some retries counter (e.g. try 3 times and quit), so you won't get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitively not the right way ^^ you should use a callback after the upload of your file.

You upload your file and in the callback you call your addDb function